# Смена локального пользователя PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Цель: выполнять смену локального пользователя (logout и login) при определенных событиях (лок. время).

Компы вне домена.  ОС - Windows 7 Pro.

Подкиньте документации, всё что нашёл для доменной структуры. (Или нет разницы?)

Может быть я неверно выбрал инструмент? Может следует использовать ЯП? (C#?)

Comment: Сам по себе pwoershell не поддерживает интерактивный логин в систему. Попробуйте связку Task Scheduler + autologon в реестре + Powershell: PS правит реестр и перезагружает компьютер, при загрузке происходит автологон. Почитать про реестр тут: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Logout из powershell вы, разумеется, сделаете, просто используя команду logoff. Но интерактивный вход, как отмечено @n01d, из powershell невозможен.

Однако, если вам просто нужен доступ из powershell в качестве конкретного пользователя, вы всегда можете это реализовать, например, так:

```
$crd = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "имя_пользователя", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'пароль' -AsPlainText -Force)
$new_session  = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $crd -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32
```